# iphone animation - catch notification

Tags: iphone, animation

I'm using following lines of code to animate:

```
CATransition *animation = [self getAnimation:dirString];
    [[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
    [[[self view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
```

After end of animation, I want to play sound.
How can I get notification when animation is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CATransition is a subclass of CAAnimation, so it inherits (among other things) a `delegate` property, and a delegate method called `animationDidStop:finished:`. Define that method in whatever class you'd like to handle the event, and set the `delegate` property of the animation to an object of that class. When the animation finishes, the `animationDidStop:finished:` message is sent to the delegate.

For example:

```
AnimationDelegate.m
@implementation AnimationDelegate

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
     //Handle whatever needs to be done after the animation stops
}

ClassUsingAnimation.m
@implementation ClassUsingAnimation
{
    AnimationDelegate *customDelegate = [[AnimationDelegate alloc] init];
    CATransition *animation = [self getAnimation:dirString];
      animation.delegate = customDelegate;
      [[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
      [[[self view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
    [customDelegate release];
}
```